# iterate through array values and assign to new variables shell

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, for-loop, session-variables

I have an input txt file with each line representing a value I need to capture and assign to a variable for processing. I have created an array as seen below, but I am wanting to create a loop using these variables to process the below (bottom) if statement for each line in the .txt. I tried the following, but it doesnt iterate through, it just assigns the same value for each line:

```
for i in ${pov[@]}
do
 echo ${pov[1]}
done

output:
$ ./sed
SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
```

Here is the input and array I am using

```
##$cat seq_fy.txt
spt_seq_01,fy15
spt_seq_01,fy16
spt_seq_02,fy15
spt_seq_02,fy16

##array:
$ cat sed
pov=($(sed \n  seq_fy.txt))

##can echo pov:
$ cat sed
pov=($(sed \n  seq_fy.txt))
echo ${pov[1]}

$ ./sed
SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
```

I need to grab each pov value (${pov[1]} through [50]) and process as it does currently in an if statement/for loop as seen below, until the array is empty. An issue is there are other values determined by the pov#.

```
##current if statement being used and working after declaring each POV separately
##not using an array for the current process
if [ ! -z $pov01 ];
then
export step=${pov01//\"/}
export step03_01=$step
export pov=${pov01//\"/}
.... (using $pov as variable in connection string)
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo ${pov[i]}`, not `${pov[1]}`:

```
for i in ${pov[@]}
do
    echo ${pov[i]}
done
```

If I understand your code correctly, you can also read `seq_fy.txt` directly with a while loop:

```
cat seq_fy.txt | while read seqvar; do
    echo $seqvar
done
```

Comment: I did that originally, it basically just spits back out the input file. I know its cycling through it, but I am needing to use pov1, pov2, pov3.... as   parameters in a connection string to an external app (not relevant), so my goal is to process each line (now pov) separately until it reaches the end of the file.....something conceptually like  "for ${pov[@]} -lt 50] then export pov=$pov[i]" or " if [! -z ${pov[@]}" then export pov=$pov[i] else end".....currently I have exported each pov separately, then have an if for each one of them, but this isn't efficient